# XBOX LIVE integration to window phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to window phone application development. My client require that our game have xbox live enable for leader-board and achievement posting in same way iphone have game center for this. and also user must be able to post their score on Facebook and Twitter. I have herd that XBOX LIVE is used for leaderboard and achievement, but can't find any good tutorial on how to do it. please advice how can i implement all these. which library should i use. Is there any good tutorial on the subject?

Till now i have tried [this](http://briansolli.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/online-leaderboard-for-your-wp7-game/) tutorial. But i think it can't work with xbox live account.

If you think this question is inappropriate to ask, let me know, i will delete it ASAP.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For using Xbox Live features your application must be approved and "promoted" for this label. Microsoft says that Xbox Live label is exclusive for best games, so if you are sure that your game meets Microsoft expectations try contact with Xbox Live team via email: wpgames@microsoft.com

Comment: actually, my game is still in development stage. my role in this project is to make it social. so i don't have game ready now. will microsoft allow me to test it without having completed game?

Comment: You can try contact with them and ask. If they decide that your game is really good Microsoft will give SDK to you and you will have ability to test it.

Comment: BTW, you can see other social services, such as scoreloop.com or others.

Comment: The email doesn't exist, I got a failed response, when I tried sending a mail on it. Probably they changed it.